# Let $X$ be a compact space such that all points are isolated. Then $X$ is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact space such that all points are isolated. Then $X$ is finite.

Some help, thanks.

Comment: What is your _definition_ of compactness? There are three or four definitions that I can think of. While they turn out to mean the same thing in the end, which one you use greatly changes how you would go about proving this.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\;X\;$ is infinite, then $\;\{\{x\}:\;x\in X\}\;$ is an infinite open cover of $\;X\;$ which has no *finite* subcover, contradiction.